# js async data from json to array

Tags: json, asynchronous

How can I get JSON data with async and send them to variable or process them in any way? Really can't understand that.

```
let FormEntries=[];
    
async function getUserAsync(){
let response = await fetch(`myremotejson`);
let data = await response.json()
return data;
}

function processData(data){
console.log(data) //returns 'undefined', 'cause data didn't come to function?
FormEntries = data; //does nothing, 'cause data didn't come to function?
}


getUserAsync()
  .then(data => console.log(data)) //returns data - OK
  .then(data => processData(data)) //I want to send these data to my FormEntries array, HOW?
``
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const getUserAsync = async () => {
let response = await fetch(`myremotejson`);
let data = await response.json();
 processData(data);
};

function processData(data) {
console.log(data) ;
FormEntries = data; 
};

getUserAsync();
```